# Google Maps for ExpressionEngine returning no results for zipcodes that exist

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps

We are using the add-on on a German site using the following code to fetch results within 50km of the town/city or postcode searched;

```
{exp:gmap:search
    cache_post="false"
    channel="salons_de"
    latitude_field="cf_salons_de_latitude"
    longitude_field="cf_salons_de_longitude"
    distance_field="distance_max"
    metric="kilometers"
}
    <div class="txt"  style="float:left; margin-right:30px;">
        <input type="text" name="location" value="{if post:location}{post:location}{/if}" placeholder="Stadt oder Postleitzahl eingeben" />
        <input type="hidden" name="status" value="open" />
        <input type="hidden" name="distance_max" value="50" />
    </div>

    <input class="viewbtn3" style="float:left;" value="Suchen" type="submit">
{/exp:gmap:search}
```

However, it’s not returning results for 'some' zipcodes, even though I’m searching for the exact zipcode entered for an entry.

Wondered if anyone else has had experience with this? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to point others in the right direction, I answers this question on Devotee. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/google-maps/viewthread/9952

From Devotee:

> I am away from my computer traveling to PeersConf this week. I will get back with in detail when I can but essentially you need to geocode two fields. 1) being the zip code 2) a hidden field with “, Germany” hardcoded. This will ensure all the geocoder requests are applicable to Germany.

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to update this one as well. As you will see from the link that Justin shared, I replied to confirm the solution working. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hey Tom. A little confused - it was my question initially. I marked Justin's reply above as the answer. :)

Comment: What Tom meant is you were correct to mark Justin's answer as accepted, but no need to post a new "answer" saying that. I've converted your answer into a comment to make it clear you support this answer :)